# Why is the value of sine different for same $\theta$ in two triangles in different quadrants?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

In a video lecture, we are finding why $\cos(90^\circ+\theta)=-\sin\theta$ using a unit circle.

His proof:

$\triangle ONC \cong \triangle BMO$

Take $ON$ as $-ON$ as it is on negative $x$-axis.

Now,

In $\triangle ONC$,

$$\cos(90^\circ+\theta)=\frac{-ON}{OC}=-ON$$

Now ON = BM  (since $\bigtriangleup ONC$ is congruent to $\bigtriangleup OMB$)

In $\bigtriangleup OMB$,

$\sin \theta = BM$

Therefore,

$\cos (90 ^\circ + \theta) = -BM = - \sin \theta$

My doubt:

If we don't consider the case that these two triangles as congruent and instead in $\bigtriangleup ONC$,

$\sin \theta = -ON$

and $\cos (90 ^\circ + \theta) = -ON$

therefore,

$\cos (90 ^\circ + \theta)$ should be equal to $\sin \theta$ which is not what my teacher has suggested.

My questions are:

1. In the second triangle, $\sin \theta = BM$ is positive whereas in the first triangle, $\sin \theta = -ON$ is negative. Why so for the same angle?
2. Why we cannot proof the identity just by considering the first triangle and it should be same as the standard identity for $\cos (90 ^\circ + \theta)$?

Comment: Note:  $\triangle ONC$ is NOT $\cong \triangle OMB$.  This would imply among other things, the two horizontal sides, ON and OM are congruent.
Note:  $\triangle ONC$ IS $\cong \triangle BMO$, which agrees with your later statement, OM + BC.  Remember, in statements of congruency, the letter ordering matters and can be a useful shortcut for pulling out congruent sides.  Maybe google CPCTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin \theta = ON$, not $-ON$.

$\cos 90^\circ+\theta = -ON$ because $90^\circ + \theta$ is measured from the positive $x$-axis, and thus its cosine is defined as the $x$-coordinate, which is negative in that zone.

But in calculating $\sin \theta$, the particular angle $\theta$ is not being measured from the positive $x$-axis. Instead you are using the $\text{Sine} = \dfrac{\text{Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$ formula. That formula holds for $0^\circ<\theta < 90^\circ$ where the sine is positive, as are all distances.